# Show embedded select box on overflow, out of popup container

Tags: css, jquery-ui, z-index, jquery-ui-selectmenu

I am having a popup page,in that page i have a select box, which i have applied jquery UI selectmenu. The problem is that the selectbox is in the bottom of the popup, and when it gets open, it get out of the popup limits.

> My actual code (I cannot paste here my code for security reasons) has:
>
> - The z-index of of the select box is bigger compared to pop up container´s one, so its rendering on top of the pop up with no-issues.
> - The z-index for the select box is in relative with the pop up,not with the whole page,so the select box is hiding behind the pop-up when
>     the pop up height is less.

The desired behaviour is when popup height is less than needed to show all the select box.  I need to show the select box without hiding.

If i did not apply jquery ui select menu, it´s working as expected.

Please find the below images for reference.

- 1.When having enoug popup size.
  [image]
- 2.when popup size is less ,select is hiding.
  [image]
- 3.What i am expecting.
  [image]

Please suggest me what i can do to solve this.

Comment: Please add a piece of code with your DOM structure and CSS rules and maybe we will be able to help you in a better way, not just "suggesting" which one could be your problem

Answer (score 0):

Add CSS property `overflow-y:visible` on the main popup div:

This will make the inner content that is outside the main div top/bottom bounds to be rendered.

```
popupSelector {
   overflow-y: visible;
}
```

Here is the [documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_overflow-y.asp) about overflow-y

Comment: Thanks for the reply.I am aware that we can do like that.But i want to acheive the same using z-index,not via increasing width or using overflow.

Comment: as they said: "Tere's no way in CSS to make a child of an overflow: hidden element show it's contents outside the parent borders, you must change the hierarchy"

Comment: oh..Ok
But somehow the basic select box with out any styles doing the Job correctly.

Comment: I could not able to share the code due to some security.When i replace html dropdown with jquery-ui dropdown only issue is arising.I have tried a lot of ways to overcome.But its not happening without hierarchy change.So as of now i have removed jquey-ui stylings.

Comment: I think you will need to make an overflow-y or a hierarchy change, to take the select out of the parent div...(i´d do it with the overflow)...

Comment: anyway, styling a select is VERY HARD, check this before trying: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750006/why-is-it-so-hard-to-style-select-and-option-elements/30750206#30750206

Comment: overflow is not needed in my case,i can even extend the height of my pop up div to the extent i require,But i dont want to do that,as it will look ugly.
i will check the link you mentioned.
Thank you for all the support :)

Comment: maybe creating a transparent div.,... like... `div{popup, transparendiv}` ?