# Why is it so hard to style <select> and <option> elements?

Tags: html, css, browser

Can any browser developer, or anyone who knows why it is so difficult (if not impossible) to style the dropdown list of a `<select>`, there's any "real explanation" that prevents browsers treat the `<select> <option>` in a more convenient way.

Every time I see questions like [How to modify CSS of a  dropdown?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30748110/how-to-modify-css-of-a-select-dropdown#30748110) in different sites that receive answers like

"It's not possible to style the dropdown list of a html select. But you can build your own dropdown list or use a framework like bootstrap."

or

"If you decide that it's absolutely a good idea to customize a dropdown, then you should use JavaScript".

And I really don't know why, I know now the `<select>`, I mean the container box, can be styled  a little more using

```
select {
   -webkit-appearance: none;
   -moz-appearance: none;
   appearance: none;
}
```

And then giving our styles, which is not as simple as all say because we have to do some tricks to make it right, especially with the famous litter arrow.

As time passes we are neglecting such a simple and comfortable as the `<select>` element and almost all the developers opted to use some of the answers above and at least I still do not know why.

So at least I will be grateful if someone could help me.

Comment: What exactly is your question? Why they (= browser devs and standardization committees) didn't implement the ability to style that tag or how to do it?

Comment: If you are targeting a very specific audience, you should probably ask this at a more specific place, e.g. the developer mailing list for Firefox.

Comment: @Teolha, if there is an easy way to do it with css of course, I'll be happy to hear it, but the question concerns that there is no convenient way to do it

Comment: @Teolha: The word "why" occurs in the question no fewer than *four* times, including the title, and the only appearance of "how" is in the title of an unrelated question. While this question could be seen as a rant, it is abundantly clear that it is a "why" question. See also: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/246665/why-do-people-ask-why-questions-with-the-why-capitalized-and-excessively-for

Comment: @BoltClock, English is not my first language, please do not focus on every word or grammar, this is a matter of years, and nothing has changed at all, the only thing that has been done is put it aside, I don't know where this better located, I just want an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Dropdown lists are *highly* dependent on the system they're running on. Just look what they look(ed) like on iOS:

[image: iOS]

The `<select>` element is giving you a uniform way to mark up the functionality of a list of options which can be selected. **How that list is represented is entirely up to the browser, and the browser can implement it in the best possible way for the given circumstances.** As such it makes no sense to try to "style" it in any way, because you cannot predict how it's going to be presented in the first place.

Usually every operating system a browser runs on has native dropdown lists, and they can look very differently on different systems. The idea is that the `<select>` element can use the native dropdown list style of the underlying operating system.

It's not that it's "hard" to do, it's that styling a dropdown list makes no sense given the presentation-neutral priorities the `<select>` element embodies. It is the *lowest common denominator* of what a dropdown list is across all systems, hence system-specific styling makes no sense.

Comment: I do not mean that they give style to the list, but they can provide an easy way to do it

Comment: I think the question is valid. For example, if you have a very specialized design you should be able to adapt the colors and general appearance. Of course the usability should be as intact as possible :)

Comment: The presentation of `select` elements as determined by user agent defaults is fine, however I fail to see sufficient argument for preventing these being overridden easily as with other elements. If it is a case of 'browser knows best' then they should simply be locked out of any change, instead of it being so absurdly abstracted away from the control every other element allows. It would be nice to establish where in (any) spec it is stated that select inputs should attract this level of browser based control over their presentation.

Comment: @Yand How do you "provide an easy way to do it" when there's a theoretical infinite number of different ways the list may be presented in the first place and you'd need to customise your customisations for every single one of them?

Comment: @SW4 If you want native dropdown lists of the underlying OS, use `<select>`. If you want to eschew that convenience and reimplement your own style of dropdown list and take on the responsibility of ensuring it works everywhere, you can go ahead and do your own HTML-Javascript implementation. It makes little sense to "override" aspects of the default presentation when there really is **no default presentation**.

Comment: The default presentation is consistent: a group of related options of which one can be selected. This is not about overriding functional, but presentational aspects- so the fact the ability to do so is obtuse is not an argument for its necessity. If it was, the spec for `select` would clearly state this. The same argument exists for the right for any given OS to be able to determine what is best for the user, the OS has no idea about the context the control is being used in, less so above the developer implementing it- so the idea OS knows best, is not entirely correct.

Comment: @SW4 Exactly, `<select>` defines the *functional* aspect of a selection list, and defers the *presentation* completely to the user agent. How would you want to mark up presentation customisations when the presentation can clearly differ so enormously? There's no consistent colouring between different systems, so overriding any one colour may make it unreadable on another system. There's no consistent margin or padding, so overriding that may make it unusable on some systems (give it too much padding and you can end up with a column of 5-letter words on a small iOS screen).

Comment: @SW4 It's hard enough to do system specific customisations of default HTML elements when their default appearance and behaviour is defined and pretty consistent. It's simply impractical if the default presentation is nowhere near consistent across platforms.

Comment: @SW4: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html (non-normative) http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#form-controls http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/rendering.html#bindings (bindings are non-normative) There is no normative text that specifies that a form control must, or must not, be rendered according to the CSS visual formatting model. But HTML5 in particular notes that UAs *should* render them according to platform-specific expectations for the sake of consistency with the platform UI.

Comment: You are right about the no default presentation and the consistency, but why not at least let me reference to the elements and stylize them, I'll take my chances, anyway I always have more than 5 browsers open and with more than one version, I have to make sure the <select> looks good wherever I want, it will not be anything new.

Comment: @Yand Again, the specification specifically stays out of it because there is no way to make a universally applicable standard. Some browsers allow you to apply *some* customisations using vendor-specific prefixes, but why that may or may not encompass all aspects of the element is up to each vendor to decide. If they are using native dropdown lists, perhaps the underlying implementation is simply not customisable in certain ways. Perhaps it's too brittle. Perhaps it's simply not worth maintaining that API since customisations make little sense to begin with and are rarely used.

Comment: @YandY Viera: How would you *expect* the browser to apply styles? Say you have `select { background: red } option { background: yellow }` - what would you expect that to look like on iOS? What if iOS styles them differently from how you expect?

Comment: @BoltClock: I can be making a mistake, but I see no difference between a dropdown and a simple button, always than both can be treated in the same way, what you're saying applies also to the button, and not for that we can't set styles to the button

Comment: That is based on an assumption that "the select element represents the button part of a dropdown menu", which is flawed for the reasons deceze has explained above. One example of a vendor prefix for targeting the button of a dropdown menu in a platform such as Windows is IE's `select::-ms-expand` pseudo-element. As you can see, IE makes use of a pseudo-element to target the button, which means the select element represents something else entirely.

Answer (score 0):

I´ll just share here the answer I wrote yesterday after reading about selects. As it´s not the same question, I´ll not mark it as duplicated, but anyway is a little wide question to talk about.

**About selects:**
They are not usual DOM elements, and that makes them behave different from others. It seems the browser generates them outside the DOM model, and then the events like click, or keypress on options do not work.

Also attributes like size will change their behaviour (a size bigger than 1 will make it appear as a list, not a dropdown).

Check this answer:
[Check if select is displaying options](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30729501/check-if-select-is-displaying-options/30729795#30729795)

As you can see, there is an example with Jquery, then you will be able to style it, or to play with it´s properties. Also there are some useful links and the explanation for them.

Hope this explanation could help to you.

Regards