# <select> has extra padding compared to <input> with same border-width and padding

Tags: css, html-select, padding

```css
input, select { padding: 2px; border: solid 1px red; }
```

```html
<input value="Foo">
<select><option>bar!</option></select>
```

Even though these both have the same `padding` and `border-width`, the resulting `<select>` is clearly taller than its corresponding `<input>`. (tested in Firefox)

[image: <select> is taller than <input> with same padding and border-width]

Can you explain the reasoning behind the height difference? If I remove `padding` or `border-width` rules then the problem goes away. Unfortunately that's not a good solution for my project.

I am hoping to have pixel-perfect layouts that are cross-browser consistent, even with mobile browsers. Thus far, I've always been maintaining a different `padding` for `<select>` than I have for `<input>`, but would prefer if I could use one setting for both.

*We found a simple CSS rule to solve a [similar question in regarding `<button>`s in Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517744/remove-extra-button-spacing-padding-in-firefox). I know it may not be so simple for `<select>` I posted this question to find out for sure.*

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why is it so hard to style <select> and <option> elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750006/why-is-it-so-hard-to-style-select-and-option-elements)

Answer (score 0):

You really can't style `<select>` elements with css and expect them to look the same on different browsers - or even expect your rules to be applied for that matter.  Browsers all handle form elements in their own special way - if you want something that looks the same everywhere I suggest you try [Select2](https://select2.github.io/) or a similar replacement plugin.

Even your snippet for example, in Chrome on OS X 10.8 the `<input>` is actually taller than the `<select>` and does not resemble your screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I already knew they would not look exactly the same, but I did think they were consistently taller. It is interesting to see that the select is actually shorter in OS X.

Comment: It seems that the `<select>` is taller in Chrome and Firefox on Windows, as well as Chrome on Android/Chrome OS. If there was some hidden CSS rule I could disable (i.e. similar to what we found when [researching `<button>` padding](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5517744/remove-extra-button-spacing-padding-in-firefox)) Then I would be quite happy with that level of consistency. Having small display differences in OS X (a smaller percent audience than the aforementioned) would be acceptable given the current level of standardization.

Comment: it's just one of those irritating things about front end web design that's a complete coin toss.  it varies from browser to browser and OS to OS - even different versions of the *same OS* can render different height, width, borders, etc.  As cumbersome as it may be, that's why I suggested using Select2 or something along those lines.

Answer (score -1):

Every browser has its default css and so you can not trust on displayed height and margins and other properties except you clear all default styles and set your own values. I suggest adding `height` and `box-sizing` and also `vertical-align` to gain your own result:

```css
input, select { 
  padding: 2px; border: solid 1px red;
  height:20px;
  box-sizing:border-box;
  vertical-align:middle;
}
```

```html
<input value="Foo">
<select><option>bar!</option></select>
```

Comment: I want the height to be automatic based on font size. In your snippet, the text of the select is partially cropped: http://i.stack.imgur.com/bg6Xe.png. I am hoping for a rule that disables the extra (browser-specific) spacing.

Comment: Looking at your post again, I do like the idea of using a larger (less likely to be cropped) `height`, and then removing the vertical padding. This with `vertical-align: middle` makes for a pretty cool way to get consistency, but I'm not sure of the compatibility of `vertical-align` between `<select>` and `<input>` and also across other browsers.

Comment: Text of input and select field are automatically vertical aligned. However using `line-height` and `height` together is safer. `vertical-align:middle` makes the input and select to stay in same baseline.