# Why is the text in the select tag and input tag aligning differently?

Tags: html, css, select, input, text-align

As you can see in the image below the "Ms." in the select (first one) is aligned differently than in the input (second one), although both have the same width and both text's alignment is set to "left.

How can I get rid of that extra space on the left inside the select tag?

Here the Snippet:

```css
.select, .input {
  width: 45%;
  text-align: left;
  height: 1.5rem;
  background-color: transparent;
  display: block;
  border-width: 0 0 2px 0;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: mediumslateblue;
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  margin-left: 10%;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" class="input" value="Hello" />
<select name="" id="" class="select">
  <option value="">Hello</option>
</select>
```

[image: Different alignment]

Comment: This definitely looks like a padding issue, do you have the complete code with HTML as well to check in a sandbox so that we can see? Create a [mre] here, please?

Comment: (Kinda weird to see a Title/Salutation input in a modern form today - they're kinda unfashionable now)

Comment: `width: 45%;` <-- This does not do what you think it does. Also, we need to see your outer HTML and CSS of all relevant containers, because `width: n%` is proportional to an element's parent, and you haven't shown us what the parents/containers are.#

Comment: This is a known problem with the select tag's implementation. Check the answer from the [dupe question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27508479/) so it helps.

Comment: Fun-fact: styling `<select>` elements is a pain because browser-handling is inconsistent and the HTML spec allows this - as input/form-controls are intended to be platform/device-native widgets: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30750006/why-is-it-so-hard-to-style-select-and-option-elements

Comment: @Dai The computed width is the same for both elements.